# children() only selecting first child

Tags: jquery

Given the following unordered list:

```
<ul class="nb">
    <li class="home"><a href="index.html" class="current"><span class="displace">Home</span></a></li>
    <li class="products"><a href="products.html" title="Products"><span class="displace">Products</span></a></li>
    <li class="services"><a href="services.html" title="Services"><span class="displace">Services</span></a></li>
    <li class="support"><a href="support.html" title="Support"><span class="displace">Support</span></a></li>
    <li class="company"><a href="company.html" title="Company"><span class="displace">Company</span></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html" title="Contact"><span class="displace">Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Can you tell me why the following only selects the first list item:

```
var status = 'closed';
$('ul.nb li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        if ($status == 'closed'){
            var li = $(this).closest('li');
            var items = li.parent().children();
            console.log(items.html());
        }
});
```

Expected results are a selection of all list items, console shows
`<a href="index.html" class="current"><span class="displace">Home</span></a>`

TIA

Comment: Have you confirmed that `li.parent()` is doing what you think it should? Also, is there a reason you don't simply do `var items = $(this).closest('ul').children();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`html` as getter only returns html content of the first selected element, `items` in your code is a jQuery wrapped array of all the selected `li` elements. http://jsfiddle.net/MKUGv/

Answer (score 1):

Because [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't go through each element of the jQuery object and concat all their html values. It only returns the first one's html value.

Since `li` is all the children, you will have to loop through them on your own. Something like:

```
var html = '';
items.each(function(i, elm) {
    html += $(elm).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for... (logging the html for each li)

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Rhx/

```
$(items).each(function() { console.log($(this).html()) });
```

Comment: `items` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again.